# Probability: $ (A'\cap B' \cap C' ) $ and $ (A \setminus (B \cup C )) $

Tags: probability

how can I find the probability of the two events:

$ P(A)=\frac{1}{2},P(B)=P(C)=\frac{1}{3}, \\
P(A\cap B)=P(B\cap C)=\frac{1}{12}, P(A\cap C)=\frac{1}{9};\\
P(A\cap B\cap C)=\frac{1}{36}$

1. $ (A'\cap B' \cap C' ) = ?$
2. $ (A \setminus (B \cup C ))=? $

any tips/solutions on how to go about questions like this?

Comment: What is $A'$ ?  the complement of $A$ ? (this is however not a standard notation for the complement)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

I denote $A^c$ the complement of $A$ instead of $A'$.

$$A^c\cap B^c\cap C^c=(A\cup B\cup C)^c.$$
Also,

$$\mathbb P(A\setminus (B\cup C))=\mathbb P(A)-\mathbb P(A\cap (B\cup C).$$